# Expected behaviour of query notifications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linux, odbc, event-notification

I am using the [Microsoft ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server#microsoft-odbc-driver-131-for-sql-server) on a Linux system to connect to SQL Server 2012 on Windows to use the [Query Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/working-with-query-notifications) feature. I run my C code and can see my subscription appear in `sys.dm_qn_subscriptions` as I expect, then my code sends a `WAITFOR` and blocks - fine so far. Then I do a transaction that will trigger the notification, and I get it - still fine. What I would like to do is then process the notification and loop around again to `WAITFOR` but after the first notification my subscription no longer appears in the DMV. My question is, is this the intended behaviour and I should re-subscribe every time, or is something weird happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query notification is removed after the message is sent so you'll need to re-subscribe if you want to continue to receive notifications. Here's the relevant excerpt from the doc you referenced.

> Notifications are sent only once. For continuous notification of data
>   change, a new subscription must be created by re-executing the query
>   after each notification is processed.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that - thanks! I must have read that page a dozen times...